# How to show two Routes at the same time in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend

In React project, whenever I run my server, I only get `<Home/>` page not the `<Layout/>` page, loaded on the server. How can I get both pages loaded at the same time on the server?

```
// App.js

import './App.scss';
import { Router , Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
   <Routes>
   <Route path="/"  element={<Layout />}/>
   <Route index element={<Home/>} />
   </Routes>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```
// Layout.js

import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';

import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Sidebar />  {/* Code for Side bar is given below */}
        <div className="page">
          <span className="tags top-tags">&lt;body&gt;</span>
          <Outlet />
          <span className="tags bottom-tags">
            &lt;/body&gt;
            <br />
            <span className="bottom-tag-html">&lt;/html&gt;</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
export default Layout;
```

```
// Home.js

import './index.scss'

const Home =()=>{
    return(
    <div className="container home-page">
        <h1>Hi, I am<br/></h1>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae magnam nesciunt dicta eos.</p>

    </div>
    
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Second part of the code is for <Layout/>

Comment: Third part of the code is for </Home>